# EF 6 Code First Migrations vs dbinitializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When i start my first EF, i used `DbContext` with  `Database.SetInitializer` in the constructor calling a derived class from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>` i'm able then to drop recreate database from scratch,  however i came a cross the Migration which i totally don't know why using migration over my older approach? also i noticed that `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>` doesn't work with `IdentityDbContext` i got the error: `The model backing the 'IdentityDb' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).`

Migration vs dbinitializer 
If the purpose is the same why using Migration over dbinitializer ?
Maybe i'm comparing two different things but all what i can say is that i'm totally lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DbInitializer creates that database from scratch. Thats it.

Migration provides more than the DbIntitializer.

**Database Version Control**

Migration allows you to save every changes done to your database, every database update is stored, ultimately creating revision checkpoints. Similar to a *source control* if you're familiar.

You can migrate to a specific version, forward or backward. For example, you can downgrade from version 4 (latest) to version 2, and you'll only lose the data from the columns/tables you removed.

Lets say your database looks like this in version 4.

```
Version 4
ID    | FirstName     | LastName
--------------------------------
1     | John          | Smith
2     | Michael       | Smith
```

Version 2 has no `LastName` column and if you migrate from 4 to 2, that means that you'll retain the data for `ID` and `FirstName`.

```
Version 2
ID    | FirstName     
-----------------
1     | John          
2     | Michael
```

**Extracting the Sql Script**

Migration allows you to create upgrade and downgrade sql scripts. Using DbInitializer, how are you suppose to update the production database? Manually? create a hail-mary-script?

With Migration, if something went wrong during deployment, the deployment team can easily downgrade the database (no harm done)

**Additional Database Annotations**

With migration, you can customize how your database is going to look like. For example: Columns with default values? Migration got you covered.

**Data Motion**

I assume your database does not have any **required** initial data yet, like items for DropDownList options. With Migration, you can customize your update sql scripts to setup initial data. For example: List of countries.

Another scenario is moving your data, lets say you decided to split up the column Name to FirstName and LastName.

**Fresh Start**

Of course, Migration allows you to create a database from scratch, just like DbInitializer.

**Tutorial:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621

Answer (score 1):

You said yourself you are *dropping* your database.  Migrations preserve data.  That's an enormous advantage -- you certainly don't want to drop your database in production, I presume.

Comment: what about development env where i don't mind dropping my database?

Comment: Databases exist to preserve data.  How do you intend to modify the production schema without dropping your data?